# Can I add OBject of button to NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create number of buttons on view programatically and for that I need array, so can I add button object in `NSMutableArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that see the following code

```
// Create buttons for the sliding menu. For simplicity I create 5 standard buttons.
NSMutableArray  *buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 for(NSInteger i = 0; i < [self.slideMenuArray count]; i++)
 {
     // Rounded rect is nice
     UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

     NSString *title=[slideMenuArray objectAtIndex:i];

     [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 4.0f, 90.0f, 20.0f)];
     [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithString:title] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
     [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [[btn titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];

     [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     UIImage *backgroundView;
     if(i==0)
     backgroundView= [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnclk.png"];
     else
     backgroundView= [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn.png"];    
     [btn setBackgroundImage:backgroundView forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [buttonArray addObject:btn];

 }
```

You can retrieve the added button objects like this-

```
for(int i = 0; i < [buttonArray count]; i++)
    {
        UIButton *btn = [buttonArray objectAtIndex:i];

        // Move the buttons position in the x-demension (horizontal).
        CGRect btnRect = btn.frame;
        btnRect.origin.x = totalButtonWidth;
        [btn setFrame:btnRect];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

sure you can, and remember that when you do, every button or other object will be retained bu the array and released when you remove it from the array...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) can hold any objects